# How to limit wordpress the_excerpt() dynamically

Tags: posts, excerpt, the-content

I'm trying to limit WordPress post excerpt and I've tried some ways to do it but all of them was not the stuff that I need, to say concisely I want to limit post excerpt with a number that I use everywhere with differences.

For example, I need to make something I use it like this:
`<?php the_excerpt('30') ?>`
with this part of the code, I wanna limit my excerpt to 30 chars and in another place, I wanna use a different value like:
`<?php the_excerpt('150') ?>`
Is it in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/), it is more correct to change the length of the excerpt using add_filter:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function(){
    return 10;
});
```

you can make your own function based on this, like this:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt', 10, 1);
function new_excerpt( $lenth ){
    return $length;
});
```

...

```
apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 150 );
```